# github get_organization gives Not Found Error github.GithubException.UnknownObjectException: 404

Tags: python, github-api

I am trying to screen some github repos. I have a list of organizations that I want to screen. For some it is working fine, for other I am getting 404 Not found error even though they actually exist:

```
github_api = Github(github_access_token)
print(github_api.get_organization('eosforce').get_repos())
```

```
 File "C:/Users/haase/Documents/VL/cryptodevel/create_repos.py", line 100, in <module>
    print(github_api.get_organization('eosforce').get_repos())
  File "C:\Users\haase\Documents\VL\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\github\MainClass.py", line 296, in get_organization
    headers, data = self.__requester.requestJsonAndCheck("GET", f"/orgs/{login}")
  File "C:\Users\haase\Documents\VL\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\github\Requester.py", line 353, in requestJsonAndCheck
    return self.__check(
  File "C:\Users\haase\Documents\VL\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\github\Requester.py", line 378, in __check
    raise self.__createException(status, responseHeaders, output)
github.GithubException.UnknownObjectException: 404 {"message": "Not Found", "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/orgs#get-an-organization"}
```

For example, this works fine:

```
print(github_api.get_organization('bitcoin').get_repos())
```

Does anybody have any idea where can be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the problem here is that all organizations you want to get repos don't necessary have an `organization account` on Github.

For example:

- [eosforce](https://github.com/eosforce) has a Github `user` account.
- [bitcoin](https://github.com/bitcoin) has a Github `organization` account.

Therefore, the endpoint you uses: `https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/orgs#get-an-organization` which only work for organizations, will return a not found http status for organization with user account (like [eosforce](https://github.com/eosforce)).

---

The first step of your implementation should be to check whether the account you want to get repositories is an user or an organization account.

Then, to get user repositories, consume:

`https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/repos#list-repositories-for-a-user`

And to get organization repositories, consume:

`https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/repos#list-organization-repositories`

See the [Github documentation about Repositories](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos) for more details about how to consume those endpoints, if needed.